# Django REST framework: Dynamic serializer relation field - POST pk but GET hyperlink

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my models, I have "states" and "countries". One country can have many states.

HTTP GET state with PK 1:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "url": "http://test.com/states/1/",
    "name": "Ohio",
    "country": "http://test.com/countries/2/"
}
```

I like returning a hyperlinked related field for country in the representation above. However, it forces me to POST the hyperlinked URL when making updates to states, which can be cumbersome for clients. I would prefer to only POST the primary key of the country, like this:

HTTP PUT/POST:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "url": "http://test.com/states/1/",
    "name": "Ohio",
    "country": 2
}
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

For reference, here are other components:

Models.py

```
class State(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name='states', null=True)

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
```

Views.py

```
class StateViewSet(ExpandModelViewSet):
    queryset = State.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StateSerializer

class CountryViewSet(ExpandModelViewSet):
    queryset = Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer
```

Serializers.py

```
class StateSerializer(ExpandModelSerializer):

    country = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='country-detail', queryset=Country.objects.all(), allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name', 'country')


class CountrySerializer(ExpandModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ['id', 'url', 'name']
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set simply the readonly to true `read_only=True`, he does not oblige you to insert the whole link, just the id will be sufficient:

```
class StateSerializer(ExpandModelSerializer):

     country = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(read_only=True, view_name='country-detail', queryset=Country.objects.all(), allow_null=True)

     class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'name', 'country')
```

and in your data send `country_id` key instead of `country`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. When I POST or PUT with the "country" property set to just an integer, nothing happens

Comment: You should send the key country_id

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. That seems less elegant, though, than having the client interact with a single property name?

Comment: it is how it is recommended in DRF doc, so it ok. In fact you can choose any key name when sending the data but when saving to the database you should take in consedration what keys accept to database.

Comment: Thanks, I'll defer to the design geniuses at DRF :) I didn't see that in the docs in my first go-around

Comment: Great DRF is really powerful and well documented ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe serializer method fields are what you are looking for, you can then in the serializer method grab and inspect the request method and with the help of that return your attribute serialized in your preferred way.

Reference:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield