# Django rest framework GET all data but POST pk

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an API and trying to figure out how to return all data from my `Shipping` model into the GET method, but still sending the pk through the POST method.

I already read some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278408/django-rest-framework-dynamic-serializer-relation-field-post-pk-but-get-hyper) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37213416/django-rest-framework-get-all-data-in-relation), but it didn't solve my entire problem, at some point I need two different behaviors from my API, where the client need to send only the primary key.

I expect this in my GET `/Shipping`:

```
[{
    "pk": 1,
    ...
    "city_of_origin": {
        "pk": 1,
        "name": "San Francisco",
        "state": {
            "pk": 1,
            "initial": "CA",
            "name": "California"
        }
    },
    "destination_cities": [
        {
            "pk": 2,
            "name": "San Jose",
            "state": {
                "pk": 1,
                "initial": "CA",
                "name": "California"
            }
        },{
            "pk": 3,
            "name": "Los Angeles",
            "state": {
                "pk": 1,
                "initial": "CA",
                "name": "California"
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

And this in my POST:

```
[{
    "pk": 1,
    ...
    "city_of_origin": 1,
    "destination_cities": [2, 3]
}]
```

I've been trying to change my `serializers.py`:

```
class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = State

class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    state = StateSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = City

class ShippingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city_of_origin = CitySerializer()
    destination_cities = CitySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Shipping
```

It worked well returning all data, however it changed all my API Root forms, forcing to create a city and a state nested to my Shipping, where I had a dropdown menu with the cities before I changed my serializer. However the exhibition of this dropdown is the behavior I expect on the POST Form.

Here it's my `models.py`:

```
class Shipping(models.Model):
    city_of_origin = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='origin', default=None)
    destination_cities = models.ManyToManyField(City, related_name='destiny', default=None)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=True, max_length=255)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=True, max_length=255)
    initial = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to thank in beforehand all the help you guys can provide me.

EDIT:
I'm using Django 1.9.5 and Django rest framework 3.3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `get` and `post` are being handled by the same rest api view, I think you are using something like a `ViewSet` (or an appropriately mixed GenericAPIView). Your `ViewSet` will use a different serializer for getting and for posting.

For getting/listing you will use the one you already created (let's rename it):

```
class ShippingGetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city_of_origin = CitySerializer()
    destination_cities = CitySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Shipping
```

For posting:

```
class ShippingPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city_of_origin = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    destination_cities = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Shipping
```

Your ViewSet would have a definition of `get_serializer()` like this:

```
class ShippingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Shipping.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return ShippingPostSerializer
        return ShippingGetSerializer
```

If you are using two different views for the get and the post entry point, create each one assigning them the `serializer_class` class attribute to the appropriate serializer as I wrote.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention it, but I was using this kind of ViewSet with `ModelViewSet` and default declarations of queryset and serializer class. Your solution worked perfectly well, I am extremely grateful, thank you!